Loomis-Whitney inequality from generalized Hölder inequality
I've proven the following "generalized Hölder inequality",

Suppose $q^{-1}=\sum_{i=1}^np_i^{-1}$ for $1\leq q,p_1,...,p_n\leq\infty$, then $$||\prod_{i=1}^nf_i||_q\leq\prod_{i=1}^n||f_i||_{p_i}$$

and am now trying to use it to prove the following version of the Loomis-Whitney inequality as an exercise:

If $\pi^{\hat{j}}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ denotes the projection map  $\pi^{\hat{j}}(x)=\left(x_1, \ldots, x_{j-1}, x_{j+1}, \ldots, x_n\right)$, then $$
\|\prod_{j=1}^n f_j \circ \pi^{\hat{j}}\|_{L^q\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)} \leq \prod_{j=1}^n\left\|f_j\right\|_{L^{(n-1) q}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})}
$$

Immediately using the first result with $p_i=nq$ gets me to $$\|\prod_{j=1}^n f_j \circ \pi^{\hat{j}}\|_{L^q\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)}\leq \prod_{j=1}^n\left\|f_j\circ\pi^{\hat{j}}\right\|_{L^{n q}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}$$ But after quite some time nothing I've attempted seems to get me anywhere. Any help would be much appreciated.

We prove this by induction with respect to $n$. Assume the inequality is true for some $n\ge1$ and all $q$.
First step is
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{\mathbb R^{n+1}} \prod_{j=1}^{n+1} |f_j \circ \pi_j|^q dx
&= \int_{\mathbb R^n } |f_{n+1} \circ \pi_{n+1}|^q \left[ \int_{\mathbb R}
\prod_{j=1}^n |f_j \circ \pi_j|^q dx_{n+1} \right] \ d(x_1\dots x_n)\\
& \le \|f_{n+1}\|_{L^{nq}(\mathbb R^n)}^q
\left( \int_{\mathbb R^n } \left[ \int_{\mathbb R}
\prod_{j=1}^n |f_j \circ \pi_j|^q dx_{n+1} \right]^{\frac{n}{n-1}} \ d(x_1\dots x_n) \right)^{\frac{n-1}n}
\end{split}
$$
where we used that $f_{n+1} \circ \pi_{n+1}$ does not depend on $x_{n+1}$. This is the main trick.
Using Hoelder inequality, we get
$$
 \int_{\mathbb R}
\prod_{j=1}^n |f_j \circ \pi_j|^q dx_{n+1}
\le \prod_{j=1}^n \left( \int_{\mathbb R}|f_j \circ \pi_j|^{qn} dx_{n+1} \right)^{\frac1n}
$$
so that
$$
 \int_{\mathbb R^n } \left[ \int_{\mathbb R}
\prod_{j=1}^n |f_j \circ \pi_j|^q dx_{n+1} \right]^{\frac{n}{n-1}} \ d(x_1\dots x_n)
\le \int_{\mathbb R^n }  \prod_{j=1}^n \left( \int_{\mathbb R}|f_j \circ \pi_j|^{qn} dx_{n+1} \right)^{\frac1{n-1}} \ d(x_1\dots x_n).
$$
In the latter integral, the function $\left( \int_{\mathbb R}|f_j \circ \pi_j|^{qn} dx_{n+1} \right)^{\frac1{n-1}}$ does not depend on $x_j$. Applying the L-W inequality for $n$ factors and $q=1$ yields
$$
\begin{split}
 \int_{\mathbb R^n }  \prod_{j=1}^n \left( \int_{\mathbb R}|f_j \circ \pi_j|^{qn} dx_{n+1} \right)^{\frac1{n-1}} \ d(x_1\dots x_n)
 &\le\prod_{j=1}^n \left( \int_{\mathbb R^n } \int_{\mathbb R}|f_j \circ \pi_j|^{qn} dx_{n+1}  \ d(x_1\dots x_n)  \right)^{\frac1{n-1}}\\
 &= \prod_{j=1}^n  \|f_j\|_{L^{nq}(\mathbb R^n)}^{q\cdot \frac{n}{n-1}},
\end{split}
$$
which finishes the proof.

This inequality is one step of the usual proof of $\|f\|_{L^{\frac n{n-1}}(\mathbb R^n)}\le \|\nabla f \|_{L^1(\mathbb R^n)}$ for $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$.

Ah, I was wondering how to use the fact that the projection map "removes" a coordinate, I was trying to do some sort of change of variables. That's very clear now, thank you
